# Aviation Overlay google maps

Tags: maps

I would like to be able to display aeronautical charts high/low similar to flight radar 24 (Will attach picture).
Is this possible please?
Not sure where I can get them from.
[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.iflightplanner.com/AviationCharts/

https://sites.google.com/site/planeslinks/maps

http://www.soaringdata.info/aviation/tifInGe.html

https://www.planeandpilotmag.com/article/google-earth-the-ultimate-preflight-tool/#.W4ugQBh9g8o

*These links might help.*

Open Google Earth.

Download the sectional charts from here:http://www.gelib.com/aeronautical-charts-united-states.htm

Double-click the download file to open it. This will automatically load it into Google Earth.

When Google Earth begins, look under Temporary Places and click on "Aeronautical Charts" to see a list of the various chart options. Click on Sectionals to open up the mosaic of the Sectionals covering the lower 48 United States.

> Note: After clicking on the Aeronautical Charts link in Google Earth,
>   it might take some time for everything to load. If it doesn't work, or
>   for more information visit the Google Earth Library.  You can also
>   select other options, such as  Flyway maps, the Sectional legends, 3D
>   Airspace, etc.

References: Wiki

Comment: Is there an update for these links? None are still good.

Comment: All the links are dead